# How our body produce different T-cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, immunology, human-genome

I've heard in many documents said that :

> There are 25 million to a billion different T-cells in your body. Each
>   cell has a unique T-cell receptor that can fit with only one kind of
>   antigen - *quoted from askabiologist*.
>
> [image: Image source : https://askabiologist.asu.edu/t-cell]

But I haven't found the mechanism of this. How our body produce too many different T-cells? Does our genome need to have 25 million to billion genes to encode for 25 million to billion unique receptor for those T-cells? Does each T-cell have a different gene region on their genome or they have a different turned-on/turned-off genes ?

Comment: You want to look for receptor re-arrangement and editing.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination